# Jquery DIV.css display none but show one div inside that div

Tags: php, jquery, css

I have a div container that contains receptacle inputs for a form at the top. So I want the div hidden, id `$('#sources').css('display','none')`

However there is one div inside all of that which I want shown. Due to the irritating source files in a series of dynamically generated options in the source receptacles I cannot find a way of separating out the div I want shown from the rest as not everything has an ID.

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is part of how HTML and CSS works. You cannot hide a parent element and still display a child element.

Perhaps you could try setting all child elements except that one to hidden.

Also, `.hide()` is an easier shortcut for `.css('display','none)`.

```
$('#sources').children(':not(#showThis)').hide()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to move the div you want shown outside the div that's hidden. It's best, obviously, to do that in the markup. If you **can't** do that in the markup for some reason, you can do it afterward with jQuery:

```
var sources = $("#sources");
var target = sources.find("selector_for_the_target_div");
sources.hide();
target.insertBefore(sources);
```

That uses [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) to move the target div outside the `#sources` div. (I also used [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), which is a shorter version of `css('display', 'none')`.)

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/arave4)

Comment: Gah! ...33 seconds too slow! +1, and my answer deleted. Darn... =)

Comment: +1. instead of creating `target` before `sources` may break the page layout, so the best approach would be to create another div, whose class/style would be same as element and than insert `target` in it.

Comment: @Adeel: Yeah, that might be a good enhancment to the above. Although if the `#sources` div *has* to be hidden, it may be that that doesn't give the result they're looking for, either. Still a useful point to make.

Answer (score 1):

No you need to place that div outside.

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a shot:

`$('#sources').children().not("#div_you_want_to_show").css('display', 'none');

Comment: Isn't that what smdrager said?

Comment: It does the same thing, just in a different way. I put this up because, maybe to some people, it is less confusing than `:not(#showThis)'`